# Arduino - String Array with integer

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

In Arduino i need a simple array. The keys have to be a string and the values an integer. In PHP it would look like this:

```
$array["name"] = array(8,4);    
$array["second"] = array(1,6);
```

Is there any way to solve this with Arduino?

Comment: Short Answer **NO**. Arduino is too low level and does not support this natively. So with no native support, you have to make something like a `HashMap` yourself. Beware, that you need to comfortable with dynamic memory allocations and pointers to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Array of struct would be better:

```
typedef struct keyAndValue_ {
    int key;
    char value[NAMELENMAX+1];
} keyAndValue_t;

keyAndValue_t myArray[] = {
   {123, "Bob"},
   {345, "Harry"}
};

for (int x = 0; x <= sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0]); x++) {
    if (myID == myArray[x].key) {
        Serial.println(myArray[x].value);
    }
}
```